# Am I able to escape inertness when using the HTML inert property?

Tags: javascript, html, html-inert

I'm building web component that contains `<dialog>` element. I'm opening the dialog with `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`, which moves the dialog to the top layer. Some of the content of the dialog is top-layer incompatible, namely, Google Recaptcha, which renders beneath the dialog.

A [number of other individuals have noted the same issue with dialog elements and ReCaptcha](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/318), and one approach appears to be to use `HTMLDialogElement.show()` instead of showModal. From a usability standpoint, I think this is acceptable, but from an accessibility standpoint, I'd really like the benefits that `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()` provide. Namely, making all other HTML elements inert and thus noninteractive and hidden from the accessibility tree. And by using the `inert` attribute or property, I can make a certain subtree of an HTML document inert myself.

As of today's date (2023-10-31), both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert) and the [HTML Living Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-inert-attribute) indicate that it's possible to "escape inertness", but this doesn't appear to be possible for HTML authors. For example, using Chrome/Edge, with the following HTML, I can't interact with the elements inside of the dialog if opened with `.show()`, when I'm attempting to deliberately "escape inertness" via setting the dialog's inert property to false.

Is it possible for HTML authors to be able to escape inertness in this way?

```js
const dialogOpener = document.getElementById("dialogOpener")
const modalOpener = document.getElementById("modalOpener")
const dialogCloser = document.getElementById("dialogCloser")
const testDialog = document.getElementById("testDialog")

dialogOpener.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  testDialog.show()
  document.body.inert = true
  testDialog.inert = false
})

modalOpener.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  testDialog.showModal()
  // modal inertness is implicit, and the following lines have no effect:
  document.body.inert = true
  testDialog.inert = false
})

document.getElementById("dialogCloser").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  testDialog.close()
  document.body.inert = null
  testDialog.inert = null
})
```

```html
<button id="modalOpener">.showModal()</button>
<button id="dialogOpener">.show()</button>

<dialog id="testDialog">
  <p>
    ... Some <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Top_layer">HTML Top Layer</a>-incompatible content here
  </p>

  <button id="dialogCloser">
    Close Dialog
  </button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: FWIW on the `show()` button your Close Dialog button does not work - is that actually demonstrative of your issue?  Perhaps add that clarification to your questions text.

Comment: The "Close Dialog" button not working with `.show()` is in fact a demonstration of the issue, in that I'm unable to escape inertness from higher up the DOM.

Comment: I suspect that the Google ReCAPTCHA is part of the document behind the modal dialog since a new dialog will surface above any existing (including other dialogs currently open). Interesting quest you are on here!.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this help you or answers the question BUT, if I swap my thought pattern to the document and set `document.body.inert = false;` in the show method I CAN click the modal - no ReCapcha here to test that concept however.

```js
const dialogOpener = document.getElementById("dialogOpener");
const modalOpener = document.getElementById("modalOpener");
const dialogCloser = document.getElementById("dialogCloser");
const testDialog = document.getElementById("testDialog");

dialogOpener.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  testDialog.show();
  document.body.inert = false;
  testDialog.inert = false;
})

modalOpener.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  testDialog.showModal();
  // modal inertness is implicit, and the following lines have no effect:
  document.body.inert = true;
  testDialog.inert = false;
})

document.getElementById("dialogCloser").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  testDialog.close();
  document.body.inert = null;
  testDialog.inert = null;
})
```

```html
<button id="modalOpener">.showModal()</button>
<button id="dialogOpener">.show()</button>

<dialog id="testDialog">
  <p>
    ... Some <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Top_layer">HTML Top Layer</a>-incompatible content here
  </p>
  <button id="dialogCloser">
    Close Dialog
  </button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Setting `document.body.inert = false` in your swapped code isn’t exactly what I’m looking for. Ideally, I’m inert-ing everything except the (non-modal) dialog, so that they’re hidden from the accessibility tree and non-interactive.